# Creating a login system for my website, navlist not working?

Tags: javascript, html, authentication

So I'm trying to make a simple login system using HTML, CSS and Javascript. No passwords, just a simple click on a button to log you in through a profile. I would have thought doing this would be easier than creating a password system, however finding examples and information on this is few and far between.

I'm currently trying to solve an issue with the userlist for the nav bar on the sign in page, as none of the user profiles are being displayed. I'm using a javascript function to produce the navbar, which (should) take the name and id from the User javascript page, then display it.

I have tried replicating other code that seems to be a functional example of what I'm trying to produce, however the 3 buttons that should be showing in the nav bar display are empty.

HTML SIGN IN PAGE:

```
<!doctype html>
<meta charset=utf-8>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
<body style="background-color:white;"></body>
<script src="index.js" type="module"></script>
<title>Sign In</title>


//Irrelevant Code Here


<main>
   <section class="signin-container">
       <h2>Select a user profile to sign in with:</h2>
       <nav class ="userlist"><p>No users were returned</p> </nav>
   </section>
</main>
```

JAVASCRIPT USER PAGE:

```
const users = [
   {
       id: '1',
       name: 'George',
   },
   {
       id: '2',
       name: 'Sam',
   },
   {
       id: '3',
       name: 'Benjamin',
   },
];


export function getAllUsers() {
   return users;
}


export function getUser(id) {
   return users.filter(user => user.id === id)[0];
 }
```

JAVASCRIPT INDEX PAGE:

```
const ui = {};
const templates = {};
const user = () => localStorage.getItem('user') ?? null;


async function getAllUsers() {
   const response = await fetch('/users');
   if (response.ok) {
       populateUserList(await response.json());
   }
}

function populateUserList(users) { //Adds users to signin page
   const userList = document.querySelector('nav.userlist');
   userList.removeChild(userList.firstElementChild);
   for (const user of users) {
       const button = document.createElement('button');
       button.dataset.user = user.id;
       button.textContent = user.name;
       button.addEventListener('click', login);
       userList.append(button);
   }
}

function populateUserData(user) {
   for (const elem of document.querySelectorAll('.username')) {
       elem.textContent = user.name;
   }
   ui.footer.loginStatus.textContent = `Welcome, ${user.name}!`;
}


async function getUserData(userid) {
   const response = await fetch(`/user/${userid}`);
   if (response.ok) {
       return await response.json();
   }
       else {
           return false;
   }
}

async function login(event) {
   const userid = event.target.dataset.user;


   const user = await getUserData(userid);
   populateUserData(user);


   localStorage.setItem('user', userid);
   if (ui.previous === 'logout' || !ui.previous) {
       window.location.href = "index.html";
   }
   else
   {
       window.history.back()
   }
   storeState();
   hideElement(ui.buttons.login);
   showElement(ui.buttons.logout);
}

function logout() {
   localStorage.removeItem('user');
   window.location.reload()
}


async function checkLoggedIn() {
   if (user()) {
       hideElement(ui.buttons.login);
       showElement(ui.buttons.logout);
       populateUserData(await (getUserData(user())));
   }
}

async function main() {
   getHandles()
   await getAllUsers();
   await checkLoggedIn();
}

main();
```

Comment: What is `getHandles()`?

Comment: Are there any errors in your dev console?

Comment: Where do you import your exported functions?

Comment: Why are you using `export`?

Comment: More to the point, why are you using `fetch` to get your users?  hint: Don't assume `response.ok` is true.  Maybe you want to catch errors at that point to see if the fetch failed.  Something like this maybe: `fetch('/users').then((response) => response.json()).then((data) => populateUserList(data)).catch((error) => console.log(error))`

Comment: You really need to create a [mre] for this question.  Even doing that will give you a much better idea of what the issues are.  You're also doing things that don't really add value in your code.  Why have an array of user objects that each have an numeric when you could literally just use the index of the array as your id.  Why use `fetch` to attempt to read a JS file as if it were JSON?  You're mixing tech.  Either `fetch` a file that contains valid JSON or import your users as JavaScript using a `<script>` tag.

Comment: @mykaf They are exported to the index javascript page, what should I be using instead of export?

Comment: At no point is your `JAVASCRIPT USER PAGE` ever being treated as if it were JavaScript.  It's being treated as an HTML file.

Comment: `exported to the index javascript page`, but there is no import statement anywhere.